# Is there a way to convert a full ZipInputStream into a single InputStream to save it as a zip file on disk

Tags: java, aem, zipinputstream

This is something to do with the AEM Translation API, the TranslationObject can give us a context package as a ZipStreamInput, we need to take that input and either convert to a Base64 String to send as part of an XML, or a way to convert to an actual zip file to save locally.

I tried quite a few things, but all resulted in a 0 byte file, most likely because of the way ZipInputStream works needing to use the getNextEntry. (Again, the usage of ZipInputStream is forced upon us by the API)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The other solution would be to extract the stream on the drive, and create a new zip from there, open that file as a inputstream to then convert, which feels quite convoluted for nothing.

Comment: Have you tried reading from ZipInputStream (using read) method into a BeufferedOutputStream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) and then just write it to a file?

Comment: Yes, it gave me a 1 byte stream with -1 in it.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using the getTranslationObjectPreview method for the stream. If that's the case then a 1 byte stream means your page previews are failing (some component exception etc. could be the case). Is the translation framework working and can translators view the pages during preview?

Comment: Yes, that's the method. And yes the preview works, as I can unzip the stream on the local drive using the same way that the bootstrap(AEM's Translation API sample project) method does.  ZipInputStream seems a strange beast, not working the same way a normal InputStream seem to work. If you call the NextEntry you do get each files, you simply cannot access the stream as a whole.